# automatically resize image and shrink their filesize

Tags: html, css, image, vba, visual-studio

I have created a dynamic website using VB and Classic-ASP. It allows co-workers to input relative data into fields on a .csv file. The changes they make go live on the website as soon as they hit save.

There is one field for images that relates to a 285px X 175px container on the site. I want them to be able to put any image in that field and the image will transform to fit the container proportionally. But I want the image file size to also be optimized according to its new dimensions in order to save load time.

Using CSS to set the img to 285x X 175px (same size as div) will do funny things to the image and doesn't optimize the file size.

Any ideas on how to go about this? JS? ASP? Any better methods? To clarify, I dont want the employees to have to resize the image before they paste it in the .csv file.

```
HTML/ASP

<img class="secondaryboxpic" src="images/<%=ins3%>"> 

CSS

img.secondaryboxpic{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -2px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width:285px;
    height:175px;
    float:left;  
}
```

Just to let everyone know, I used a complex operation with foxpro server side that grabs each image and spits out a 285px X 175px thumbnail for use of the site. Thanks for your suggestions everyone.

`You can mark this as SOLVED.`

Comment: CSS can't do anything to file size...You should optimize before uploading.

Comment: but I dont want the non techie employees to have to worry about optimizing.

Comment: What about jquery or vb? any suggestions?

Comment: Imagemagick has a convert and resize functions that can do just about anything with an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use image processing tools like `imagemagick` or web-servers' *built-in filters* (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-image-optimize).

Comment: so with imagemagick, does the every employee who is pasting files need to install the source? or just me? im a little confused at how it works but ill research it further. Thanks

Comment: It's better to write a preprocess function which will process every image and save already optimized images to display them on a web-site. The software should be installed only on a server which hosts your site and employees shouldn't be considered about that.

Comment: So I dont want to install anything new to the server, if i have to sacrifice image optimization that is fine. I just want the image to squeeze into the div and not be distorted no matter the size of the image. can that be done?

Comment: Than, if I understand your needs, you could do it with only CSS: you have to specify instead of `width` -- `max-width` and `max-height`.

Comment: I know with CSS I could just set the image width to 100% depending on if the image is wider than the div, or height to 100% if it is taller, but because I have no control of what images they input, I cant set those properties or risk distortion. Is there an ASP If Then line you could help me think up?

Comment: hsrv, what happens if the image they input is smaller then the max? do i set min values too?

Comment: if the image is bigger with `max-width` and `max-height` there is no any distortion, but if the image is smaller there is a need to point sizes in %, here is an example using only CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/qk4fn8bq/1/

Comment: Cute dogs lol, So this method works great IF I know that the image is either taller OR wider than my div. But in this case It will be random depending on the employees. I was there was a way to dynamically set the properties depending on what the employees paste in.

Comment: also I inputted an image that  has a width of 300 and a height of 445 into the field and yet the image shrinks without stretching, however it only fills half my div?

Comment: You could try `background-image` property to fill the `div` fully, but you need to specify unique CSS-class for every `div` to point to an image with CSS code `background-image: url(http://www.example.com/bck.png);`